# What happens to a Guest account when upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, upgrade

I'm presently running Windows 7 and use the Guest account.  When I run the "Get Window 10" app (the app in the the System Tray) and click the link to the "View record" from the "This PC is compatible" it says "You won't be able to use the Guest account on Windows 10".

Right now a Guest account is used by one of my kids so there are a number links, etc I want to save.

What happens to a Guest account on upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10?

Answer (score 3):

It currently is possible to use the Guest account in Windows 10.  You will just have to activate it through local group policy.

> > No, guest account is available in Windows 10 as well. It’s only that
> >     the guest user account can’t be enabled in Windows 10 via Settings or
> >     classic Control Panel. In order to enable the guest account in Windows
> >     10, you need to use the Local Users and Groups.
>
> Step 1: In the Start menu or taskbar search box, type lusrmgr.msc and
>   then press the Enter key to open Local Users and Groups.
>
> [image]
>
> Step 2: Here, on the left-side, under Local Users and Groups (local),
>   click Users.
>
> [image]
>
> Step 3: Next, in the middle pane, double-click on Users to view all
>   user accounts on your Windows 10 PC.
>
> [image]
>
> Step 4: Right-click the Guest and then click Properties or
>   double-click on Guest to open its properties.
>
> Step 5: To enable the Guest account, under the General tab, uncheck
>   the option titled Account is disabled. In the full name field, type in
>   a name for the account if you wish to have a different name for the
>   account, and then click Apply button to enable the guest account.
>
> [image]
>
> To sign in or switch to the Guest account, click on your user account
>   name on the Start menu (top-left of the Start) and then click on the
>   Guest account to switch the account.
>
> [image]

You can also within an elevated command prompt just enable the account again.

> net user guest /active:yes

[Source](http://www.intowindows.com/3-ways-to-enable-guest-account-in-windows-10)

This answer only applies to **Windows 10 version 1507** and **Windows 10 version 1511**