# What's up with guest accounts in Windows 10 and 11? Can I have one?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, guest-account

Edit re Windows 11: See new information for Windows 11 added in the answer.

---

There's a lot of confusion on the Internet, including on *SuperUser*, about guest accounts in Windows 10. I've posted this question in order to post an answer based on my research on the subject.

I won't accept my answer right away, but will wait a while to allow others to weigh in, and if someone posts a better answer, I'll accept that.

The question is: What's up with guest accounts in Windows 10? Can I have one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit re Windows 11: I'm changing over to a computer with Windows 11, so I need to answer the same question again for that. I haven't repeated all the in-depth research, but here's what I've found for Windows 11:

- DOS command `net user` and Windows `Computer Management > System Tools > Local Users and Groups > Users` still show the guest account. In the latter, it still has the property "Account is disabled".
- `Control Panel > User Accounts` no longer has `Manage Accounts`, so I don't see where to see anything about a guest account in `Control Panel`.
- The MS documentation [*Guidance for accounts on shared PCs*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/set-up-shared-or-guest-pc#guidance-for-accounts-on-shared-pcs) has been updated to say it applies to Windows 11.

  - BUT the page no longer says “We recommend no local admin accounts on the [shared] PC to improve the reliability and security of the PC.”

Because of the last point above, I don't know what to think. The doc has been updated to apply to Windows 11, but the most crucial piece of official advice not to use a guest account has been removed. Argh! So although it would be helpful to have a guest account on this new computer, I'm going to continue to not have one.

If anyone knows any better about what's going on with this in Windows 11, please post a comment or answer about it.

---

---

The short answer:

> There is a guest account in Windows 10, but it's not suitable for use on a standalone computer.

In other words:

> If your computer is not part of a network, then no, you cannot have a guest account.

The long answer:

As of Windows 10 v 1607, the guest account became part of the configuration of “shared PC mode” [[Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/set-up-shared-or-guest-pc#configuring-shared-pc-mode-on-windows), [*TechTarget*](https://searchenterprisedesktop.techtarget.com/definition/Microsoft-Windows-10-Shared-PC-Mode), [*Windows Club*](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/set-shared-pc-mode-windows-10)]. That mode is a complex configuration intended for IT professionals to set up computers dedicated to shared use. It is not suitable for a standalone computer whose owner wants to allow occasional guest use. That's because a standalone computer needs to have a local administrator account, and local administrator accounts are not recommended for computers set up for shared use, which is what is now needed to have a properly configured guest account. (See MS documentation, [*Guidance for accounts on shared PCs*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/set-up-shared-or-guest-pc#guidance-for-accounts-on-shared-pcs), which says “We recommend no local admin accounts on the [shared] PC to improve the reliability and security of the PC.”)

The bottom line:

> Owners of standalone Windows 10 computers who want to set up a guest account to maintain security when allowing a friend to use their computer are out of luck.

Here are some more details about the status of the guest account on a standalone computer:

After v 1607, the guest account still exists, but is disabled. It is included in the list of accounts obtained by:

- DOS command `net user`
- “Computer Management > System Tools > Local Users and Groups > Users”

Before v 1607, there were [four ways to enable the guest account](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/4-ways-to-enable-and-disable-built-in-guest-on-windows-10.html):

- Go to “Control Panel > User Accounts > Manage Accounts > Guest”. Select “Turn on”.
- Go to “Local Group Policy Editor (GPedit.msc) > Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options > Accounts: Guest account status > Properties”. Click “Enabled”.
- In DOS as admin, enter `net user guest /active:yes`.
- Go to “Computer Management > System Tools > Local Users and Groups > Users > Guest > Properties”. Uncheck “Account is disabled”.

As of v 1903, the first method was/is no longer possible because “Manage Accounts” does not show the account “Guest”. The other three methods were/are possible to execute, but it has been reported that doing so either has no effect or causes serious system malfunctions [[*Digital Citizen*](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/you-cant-enable-guest-account-windows-10-stop-trying), [*SuperUser* comment](https://superuser.com/questions/957676/why-is-the-guest-account-missing-broken-in-windows-10#comment1815576_979836), [*SuperUser* answer](https://superuser.com/questions/957676/why-is-the-guest-account-missing-broken-in-windows-10/#1032018), [*SuperUser* comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1348237/i-created-a-guest-account-on-windows-10-but-unable-to-sign-in-why#comment2272399_1348567)].

I found a [*SuperUser* answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1029592/how-can-i-create-a-windows-8-1-10-user-account-that-mirrors-a-guest-account/#1100974) starting with, “Here's what I did on Windows 10 to provide a user login for some visiting guests.” I did what it said, and [got access errors](https://superuser.com/questions/1499669/windows-10-error-applying-security-on-new-account-failed-to-enumerate-objects).

- (Note about the previous link: This is to a question I posted on *SuperUser* about the problem. It was "deleted" after a few months because it had a downvote and no answer. It's not actually deleted, but is hidden from most people. There is a mechanism to undelete it if it is deemed worth keeping alive. So it would be good if some people who have the right authority would take a look and see if that link ought to be allowed to work.)

Some of the wrong or misleading information on the Internet about guest accounts in Windows 10:

- The following say that the guest account has been removed or no longer works, instead of that it has been relegated to only be used on shared computers:
- [*Windows 10 build 10159 loses the Guest account*](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2943718/windows-10-build-10159-loses-the-windows-guest-account.html), *ComputerWorld*, July 2, 2015
- [*You can't enable the Guest account in Windows 10. Here's why and how others are lying*](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/you-cant-enable-guest-account-windows-10-stop-trying), *Digital Citizen*, August 9, 2017
- The article linked above for four ways to enable the guest account is no longer valid since v 1607:
- [*4 Ways to Enable and Disable Built-in Guest on Windows 10*](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/4-ways-to-enable-and-disable-built-in-guest-on-windows-10.html), iSunshare Studio, undated
- The following says to use the group policy method to activate the guest account. It cites as its source an article that has been updated to say the method no longer works:
- [*SuperUser* answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1006725/what-happens-to-a-guest-account-when-upgrading-from-windows-7-to-windows-10#1006728), Ramhound, November 29, 2015
- The following say to create and set up an account using the DOS command `net`, but this doesn't result in a real guest account, just an ordinary user account:
- [*SuperUser* answer](https://superuser.com/questions/957676/why-is-the-guest-account-missing-broken-in-windows-10/#979836/), The Professional, September 29, 2015
- [*How to Create a Guest Account in Windows 10*](https://www.howtogeek.com/280527/how-to-create-a-guest-account-in-windows-10/), *How-To Geek*, July 5, 2017
- The following article explains another way to create an ordinary user account using "Windows > Settings > Accounts". It's not wrong, but might be misinterpreted by some people as a way to set up a guest account:
- [*Create a local user or administrator account in Windows 10*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026923/windows-10-create-a-local-user-or-administrator-account), Microsoft Windows Support, last updated August 21, 2019